# Check if app has access to photos

Tags: c#, ios, permissions, unity-game-engine, privacy

I am currently using Unity and C#, and was wondering if there is a way to check if the app has access to the photo folder on an iOS device (Settings->Privacy->Photos->MyApp is checked) ?

I am currently using the Etcetera plugin (prime31) but did not see anything concerning the privacy.

What I'm doing is taking a picture and saving it to the photo folder, but if the user doesn't allow my app to access the photos this doesn't work, obviously. How do I check if I have access to be able to prompt the user ?

EDIT : Currently looking into making an Objective C library to get this information. Would really appreciate an alternative, easier solution in C#. Is this possible ?

Comment: In Unity: File>Build Settings>Player Settings> Other Settings>Camera Usage Description. Write something asking for permission to use the camera. It automatically builds in Xcode and asks the user for permission (in your words) to use the camera. They have to click 'Agree' to proceed.